# iOS - Showing background app status

Tags: ios

I'm making an app which runs in background mode for getting user's location.

Then I works perfectly, the datas are well received in background mode, but  I wanted to show a Google Maps like status when the app is in background.

Screenshot : 
[image]

( it's in french sorry, but I think you'll know what I mean ).

So, how to do this thing ? What is this feature's name ?

Thank you

Comment: This may help you, read the section titled "Using Location Services in the Background": [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/)

Comment: Do you have "always" location permission?  If so then this bar will not show since the user has given you permission to use their location always.

Comment: This is not a feature that your app "can" uses. It's a feature of iOS, if an app is using device's location in background, then system will show a banner like that. If system does not show it when your app's running in background, that means your app doesn't have the permission.

Comment: I start my app from xCode maybe this is the reason why I can't see this bar. But yes the locations are printed in the console even if the app is in background ..